# WMI Access Denied error for SCOM monitor

Tags: powershell, wmi, scom

I'm making custom a Management pack for SCOM 2012 SP1 and there is a monitor in it.
The monitor is based on the Microsoft.Windows.PowerShellTriggerOnlyProbe module and powershell script queries of WMI to remote non-domain server. This script should check a specific process on remote server.

Сorresponding рart of the script:

```
$user = "username"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred =  New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $user,$password

try {
Get-WmiObject win32_Process -Impersonation Impersonate -Authentication Packet -credential $cred -ComputerName "$serverIP" | Select Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "$Process"}
    }
Catch {
    $ErrorMSG = $_.Exception.Message.ToString()
}
```

Script **works** perfect when I run it from the powershell console under SCOM's action account, but when  I import it in the ManagementPack I get this error: `"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"` in $ErrorMSG.

Used local admin credentials on the remote server.

There is no powershell on remote server so I can't use powershell remoting, only way is to use WMI.
Please, Help!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx has some tips on troubleshooting WMI.

Comment: already read this and simiar topics, and found nothing, that can help me :(. **–E_ACCESS_DENIED** says that user doesn't have remote access to the computer through DCOM, but used account actually have and it works from the powershell console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try and run the script as System. That is the only test that should be needed if the Agent is running with the default local system account.